# Awk, not getting it right about huge values

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I am facing some problems with AWK basically there is a repo out there called [ServerStatus](https://github.com/BotoX/ServerStatus) but with some servers it's getting syntax problems with let here is the error it gets:

```
/usr/local/share/serverstatus-client.sh: line 121: let: SpeedRx=(1.10135e+10-1.10027e+10)/1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".10135e+10-1.10027e+10)/1")
```

I found it was because the grep command to get the speed of the network interfaces has an awk on it which is totally broken sometimes.

This grep with awk combined outputs numbers like 3.172+e09 which let cannot handle.

Here is the code who has the interesting part :

```sh
# Network traffic
        NET=($(grep ":" /proc/net/dev | grep -v -e "lo" -e "tun" | awk '{a+=$2}{b+=$10}END{print a,b}'))
        NetRx="${NET[0]}"
        NetTx="${NET[1]}"
        if [ "$PREV_NetRx" == "" ]; then
                PREV_NetRx="$NetRx"
                PREV_NetTx="$NetTx"
        fi
        NetRx=$(echo $NetRx | awk '{ printf("%11.3f %11.3f\n", $1,$2) }')
        NetTx=$(echo $NetTx | awk '{ printf("%11.3f %11.3f\n", $1,$2) }')
        echo $NetRx
        let "SpeedRx=($NetRx-$PREV_NetRx)/$INTERVAL"
        let "SpeedTx=($NetTx-$PREV_NetTx)/$INTERVAL"
        PREV_NetRx="$NetRx"
        PREV_NetTx="$NetTx"

        echo -e "update {$Online \"uptime\": $Uptime, \"load\": $Load, \"memory_total\": $MemTotal, \"memory_used\": $MemUsed, \"swap_total\": $SwapTotal, \"swap_used\": $SwapUsed, \"hdd_total\": $HDDTotal, \"hdd_used\": $HDDUsed, \"cpu\": ${DIFF_USAGE}.0, \"network_rx\": $SpeedRx, \"network_tx\": $SpeedTx }"
done | $NETBIN $SERVER $PORT | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' x; do
        if [ ! -f /tmp/fuckbash ]; then
                if grep -q "IPv6" <<< "$x"; then
                        echo "Connected." >&2
                        echo 4 > /tmp/fuckbash
                        exit 0
                elif grep -q "IPv4" <<< "$x"; then
                        echo "Connected." >&2
                        echo 6 > /tmp/fuckbash
                        exit 0
                fi
        fi
done
```

I tried some workarounds but i really don't understand how AWK works, could someone help me fix this command ?

Here is the output of the grep with awk :

```sh
$~ grep ":" /proc/net/dev | grep -v -e "lo" -e "tun" | awk '{a+=$2}{b+=$10}END{print a,b}'
3.84806e+09 1068117604
```

And here is the output of the grep without awk:

```sh
$~ grep ":" /proc/net/dev | grep -v -e "lo" -e "tun"
  eth0: 1505583475 9395608    0 531466    0     0          0         0 200909161 2713202    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth1: 2342591587 8367211    0    0    0     0          0         0 867289999 7634437    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not clear, please do not post samples in form f images. Always do post samples in form of text and wrap them in CODE TAGS, kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: Done corrected !

Comment: You don't need 30 lines of ill-formatted code to reproduce *`invalid arithmetic operator`*. You only need one line.  You also fail to state what line 121 is. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), etc.

Comment: I know how to debug bash it isn't the issue i am showing the code in his context, not only showing 1 line it's way more understandable when you get how it works and what is should do c:

Comment: Thanks for your answer jhnc i will look at it for now it looks really promising

Comment: Or maybe better:  `awk '{a+=$2}{b+=$10}END{printf "%d %d\n", a,b}'`. Be aware that you may get negative output if very large numbers cause integer overflow in bash.

Comment: `let` will not handle the output from `printf("%11.3f %11.3f\n", $1,$2)` too. What is that you are trying to solve? Are trying to output each INTERVAL the difference of 2nd and 10th column of the /proc/net/dev file?

Comment: Your solution worked the other one did it really well if you wish you can post an answer i'll accept it ! (jhnc the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jhnc Fixed it with

`grep ":" /proc/net/dev | grep -v -e "lo" -e "tun" | awk '{a+=$2}{b+=$10}END{printf "%f %f\n", a,b}'`

As always thanks to you all for your awesome help!

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer (comments already addressed all issues), but wanted to highlight some important notes about GNU `awk` default behavior.

The GNU `awk` program is VERY good with integers. It can represent integer up to 2^1024 (approximately 10^308), without loss of precision. On the other side, bash support for integers is based on the standard 64 signed values, with maximum value of 2^63 (about 5*(10^18)). When dealing with large numbers, better to do all math with awk, and use bash for display of stringified numbers.

When dealing with floating point numbers, GNU awk is using standard 64 floating point - about 17 digits precision (52 bit). Numbers bigger than this value are converted to integer using the high precision integer types described above.

It is interesting to note that awk is one of the few scripting engines that will promote large numbers from float to integers. Most other engines will promote large (integer) values to floating point (with lower precision) to increase the range that can be represented from the 64 bit integer (2^63, about 5*10^18) to the maximum allowed by floating point values (10^308).

On Linux, The GNU `awk` is usually compiled with the GMP and MFPR libraries, which allow for further configuration of precision, both for floating point and for integers.